# expressjs static files proxy to cdn

Tags: node.js, express

I'd like to have my images src to local but have express proxy to our CDN.

For example: `<img src="/images/logo.png" />` should actually retrieve image from our CDN at: `http://someCDN.com/images/logo.png`

express.static requires a directory which a CDN will not provide, so I was wondering if there is a work around other than 1. manually hard coding it all in the tags (terrible) or 2. writing my own proxy which detects if its image url and fetches that (i hate)

Thanks!